# Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

I've been struggling with this problem for a while and can't wrap my head around it.  I've tried a lot of the answers on the handful of other questions with the same error but none of them work, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

In my template I have a table, each row has a link to view a information about a signature:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'signatures:detail' signature.identifier %}">View</a></td>
```

In my `signatures.urls` file I have:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from signatures import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<signature_identifier>\w+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
)
```

But when I try to browse to the index (192.168.1.4:8000/signatures/), I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(u'Rediff.Messenger',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'signatures/(?P<signature_identifier>\\w+)/$']
```

And highlights the line in my template file that I've included above.

The Primary Key for the database is the "identifier" column, which is text.  This is Django version 1.7.5 on Python 2.7.5 running on CentOS 7.

I've included what I think to be relevant in the question, but the rest of the project is located on [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/ecnepsnai/Fortinet-Signature-Browser/tree/development).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you're trying to feed the `'signature:details'` URL a **string**, but in your urls.py it looks like you  only accept **digits**.

Try changing

`url(r'^(?P<signature_identifier>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),`

to:

`url(r'^(?P<signature_identifier>\w+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),`

Comment: I changed it from `\d+` to `\w+` and still get the same error message.  Oddly enough it still says "1 pattern(s) tried: [u'signatures/(?P<signature_identifier>\\d+)/$']"

Comment: Did you try resetting your server? Also, try pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `r` to clear your cache.

Comment: If by reset you mean Ctrl+c then `python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.4:8000` then yes I did

Comment: Ah, there we go.  Deleted the urls.pyc file and now the error message shows '\\w+' but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Looks like the `\w+` isn't enough - you also have a period in your signature.identifier that needs to be matched by the regex... let me see what I can find.

Comment: Try replacing the URL again with this: `url(r'^(?P<signature_identifier>.+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),`
Let me know if that works - it is not the best way to do this (the regex accepts any character), but it will let us know if the `.` is the issue.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.  I thought it might have something to do with that dot.  I also tried it with `...(.|\d)+/$'` and it seems to work.  Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I was able to help. Just one thing I want to let you know - the `.+` method I gave you is very rudimentary, and is actually considered bad practice. The better way is to combine the `\w+` with something like `\.+` (the \ escapes the `.`). I am not sure how to do this correctly, but if you can figure it out or if someone else knows, it is a preferable solution.